# How to iterate over this list and have the same length of the original list?

Tags: python

I want to have an output that has the same length as the original list.

```
listo = ['med', 'lam', 'rihanna', 'shity', 'lem']
lis = []
for i, v in enumerate(listo):
    if 'lam' in v:
        lis.append(v)
    if 'med' in v:
        lis.append(v)
    else:
        lis.append('no')
    
print(lis)
print(len(listo))
print(len(lis))
```

Comment: `elif 'med' in v:`

Comment: just make the second `if` an `elif` instead

Comment: `lis = [i if i in {'lam', 'med'} else 'no' for i in listo]`

Comment: no idea why you are `enumerate`-ing though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest change is to make the second `if` an `elif` so that only one value will be added to the output for each item in the input.

```
listo = ['med', 'lam', 'rihanna', 'shity', 'lem']
lis = []
for i, v in enumerate(listo):
    if 'lam' in v:
        lis.append(v)
    elif 'med' in v:
        lis.append(v)
    else:
        lis.append('no')
```

A more Pythonic way to write the same code is using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
listo = ['med', 'lam', 'rihanna', 'shity', 'lem']
lis = [x if x in ('lam', 'med') else 'no' for x in listo]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second if statement should be an elif. Like this:

```
listo = ['med', 'lam', 'rihanna', 'shity', 'lem']
lis = []
for i, v in enumerate(listo):
    if 'lam' in v:
        lis.append(v)
    elif 'med' in v:
        lis.append(v)
    else:
        lis.append('no')
    
print(lis)
print(len(listo))
print(len(lis))
```

When it is just a regular if the error occurs on the value 'lam'. The first if statement is true so it appends 'lam' to lis, but the second one is false so it also appends 'no' to lis.